# Error while fetching AAD app information using Get-AzureADApplication

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to fetch AAD app info using "Get-AzureADApplication" command. but getting the below error-

```
Get-AzureADApplication : You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling 
any other cmdlets.
At C:\Users\v-pasahu\Desktop\Sample.ps1:18 char:11
+ if($app = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($AppName) ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADApplication], AadNee 
   dAuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadNeedAuthe 
   nticationException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetApplication
```

Comment: It would be useful to understand more your intentions in your question. You mention in comments you want to use the non interactive flow so this should be your intentions. Also in the comments you ask for alternative methods but without knowing your intentions it is hard to answer your problem. Please tell us more about what you are trying to do :)

Comment: @PhilPeters- I have powershell script for add app roles under manifest in Azure Active Directory using Powershell script. using that script i'm getting Pop-up window for give the credential. but i want to skip those pop-up. in script i'm using Connect-AzureAD instead of this now i'm using Connect-AzureRmAccount command to skip to get pop-up window. please suggest if you have any alternate way?

Comment: Do you want an answer here or will you open another question?

Comment: Why unmark the answer? Anything else can I help you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you need to run the command `Connect-AzureAD` first.

Besides, if you do not [install azure powershell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0), you should install it before using azure ad powershell.

Comment: if we are using Connect-AzureAD we are getting pop-up for login into the azure. i dont want pop-up.. should be have any alternate way without using Connect-AzureAD.

Comment: @Pavan You could try to use [azure cloud shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview) in the portal.

Comment: i am using below command to fetch aad aap details. do we have any alternate command to fetch the details? 
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $AADAppID  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Comment: @Pavan Try to use azure rm powershell `Get-AzureRmADApplication`, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-6.6.0).

Comment: I used as per above suggestion, now getting  the below error-
Get-AzureRmADApplication : Cannot bind parameter 'ObjectId'. Cannot convert 
value "ObjID" to type "System.Guid". Error: "Guid should contain 32 digits 
with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."
At line:19 char:46
+ if($app = Get-AzureRmADApplication -ObjectId "ObjID"  -ErrorAction Si ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureRmADApplication],

Comment: @Pavan For this error, because the `ObjectId` type in [RM module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/get-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-6.6.0) is `Guid`, and the `ObjectId` type in [AD module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0) is `String`, you should use the correct type. Also, the two commands are not the same, it related to the different scenes.

Comment: Thanks Joy for help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comments you have said you want to run this in the non interactive flow. To do this you must follow the instructions here to log in as a [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0).

Alternatively depending on what you are trying to do you may find it easier to Login using the AzureRm cmdlets.