# Get-AzureADApplication throwing error while fetching Azure AD application details

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to fetch Azure AD app details using Get-AzureADApplication command.
But this command is throwing below error.

"**Get-AzureADApplication : You must call the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.
At D:\Scripts\Test.ps1:18 char:10
+ $myApp = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($AppName)' ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADApplication], AadNeedAuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadNeedAuthenticationException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.GetApplication**"

Worst part is this command was working few days back and today while executing the script. I am getting this error.
I also referred below mentioned link but not able to find solution.

[Error while fetching AAD app information using Get-AzureADApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704100/error-while-fetching-aad-app-information-using-get-azureadapplication)

Answer (score 0):

First of all do you have **Azure Active Directory PowerShell** module installed ? If yes, then login to Azure using  `Connect-AzureAD` a popup will come for you to login with microsoft credentials. If you prefer to skip login popup then follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0).

Use this small hack only for local development. Not for client/ remote machine.
To skip the Login prompt everytime you use powershell ,

- Open Windows PowerShell as an administrator
- Type Notepad $profile.
- It will open a notepad file, here you can
  paste the below code for PowerShell to log in automatically whenever
  it is opened.
- Save the file and the next time if you restart PowerShell, you can see that it will automatically login to azure portal whenever a PowerShell session is invoked.

  ```
  $username = "enter your username"
  $password = "enter password"
  $securepasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
  $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $ securepasswd)
  Connect-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
  ```

Comment: Azure AD powershell is installed and still i am facing this issue. I am using Connect-AzureRmAccount to Login as i don't want pop-up.

Comment: Ok , so you dont want popup ? If you don't mind harcoding the password into your local machine ?

Comment: $ssAADKey = ConvertTo-SecureString $AADKey -AsPlainText -Force
$psCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($AADAppID, $ssAADKey)
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $psCredential -TenantId $TenantId

Comment: I think we are diverting from the real issue , My issue is Get-AzureADapplication is throwing error not Login

Comment: Also will like to add , same code is working in my colleagues system but not mine

Comment: Same code , you mean the code from the comment or the Get-AzureADapplication ?

Comment: Get-AzureADapplication , this code worked in my system as well few days back and created script , but it started throwing errors today , don't have any idea what is happening.Following is the code throwing error

Comment: $myApp = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($AppName)'"  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzureAdApplication is from a different module (AzureAD) to Connect-AzureRmAccount (AzureRM) so I think you need to use the relevant AzureRM command instead e.g. Get-AzureRmADApplication.

As I do not know what you are trying to achieve, perhaps it is worth checking the AzureRM commands.

`Get-Command -Module AzureRM`